# Complex and multiple transform styles in angular 2+

Tags: angular, css-transforms

How can I add multiple inline transform styles in angular 2+?

This works:

```
[style.transform]="'rotate(45deg)'"
```

But when I add more than 1 style it does not work:

```
[style.transform]="'rotate(45deg) translateX(10px)'"
```

Where can I find a reference of supported `style.*` directive?
Is something like this possible?

```
[style.transform.translateX.px] = "10"
[style.transform.rotate.deg] = "45"
```

Comment: `[style.transform]="'rotate(45deg) translateX(10px)'"` should just work. Please add a plunkr / stackblitz where it does not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two methods that work:

**Method 1 - Using `ngStyle`**:

```
[ngStyle]="{'transform': 'rotate(45deg) translateX(10px)'}"
```

**Method 2 - Sanitizing the value passed to `[style.transform]`**:

```
[style.transform]="myTransform"
```

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeStyle } from '@angular/platform-browser';

get myTransform(): SafeStyle {
  return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle("rotate(45deg) translateX(10px)");
}
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mem4u6).

---

As mentioned in the question, the following syntax does not work (see [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bd8zfb)):

```
[style.transform]="'rotate(45deg) translateX(10px)'"
```

The style attribute is removed from the HTML output and this warning is triggered:

> WARNING: sanitizing unsafe style value rotate(45deg) translateX(10px)
>   (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).